# Reactor Mono, how to synch process (using .map()) and return Mono<void> from response.setComplete()

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have this method which gets redirection url and then redirect to that url

```
private Mono<Void> redirectToUrl(ServerHttpResponse response, String status) {
        String queryParameter = "?status=" + status;
        return getRedirectUrl(queryParameter)
                .flatMap(url -> {
                    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
                    response.getHeaders().setLocation(url);
                    return response.setComplete();
                });
    }
```

in the 4th line i am using `flatmap` which will modify the `response` object asynch, in that case the response will be returned to the client immediately without the redirection.

I cannot use `map()` with `response.setComplete()` because it will return `Mono<Mono<void>>`, i need to return `Mono<void>`

How can i process synchronously

```
 response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
                    response.getHeaders().setLocation(url);
                    return response.setComplete();
```

and return `Mono<void>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must process it synchronously, you could use `map()`, then call [`.then()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#then--), which will wait for the `Mono` to complete then simply relay the completion signal.

However, from my understanding the `flatMap()` call *should* work ok as-is, because the `Mono` still won't complete until that `flatMap()` completes - that should make no difference if it's asynchronous or not. I suspect the actual reason why your code isn't functioning as intended is because whatever method is calling `redirectToUrl()` isn't waiting for the returned `Mono` to complete before returning the response.

Answer (score 0):

Flatmap() also should work.
Please make sure that your getRedirectToUrl method is not returning Mono.empty().

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).